# Error when trying to insert a SUMIF function using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert a SUMIF formula into a cell using VBA. VBA is not allowing my code to run as it is. Any suggestions are appreciated.

ws and na are properly set earlier on in the code. If I simply change the SUMIF formula to a random value "x" , it appears in the desired cell. The error is occurring within the SUMIF formula that I am trying to insert into a cell.

```
ws.Range("B" & na.Row + 2).Value = "=SUMIF(OFFSET(B1,,,ROW()-1,1),"<>#N/A"))"
```

The purpose of this formula is to SUM a column of numbers while ignoring any cells that contain "#N/A".

Comment: Note: the formula works fine if I manually type it into a cell. The problem occurring is while trying to get VBA to insert that formula.

Comment: is the `#N/A` an error from a formula or a string?

Comment: I see problem with brackets: 3 times "(" and 4 times ")"

Comment: The #N/A results from a VLOOKUP formula @ScottCraner

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, it does not solve the original problem though @RafałB.

Comment: I am getting a compile error: expected expression and VBA highlights the #

Comment: And of course change .value to .formula as in answer below

Comment: (If one of the Answers worked for you, you can flag it as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post)

Answer (score 1):

When using quotes in a formula, you need to "double up":

```
ws.Range("B" & na.Row + 2).Formula = "=SUMIF(OFFSET(B1,,,ROW()-1,1),""<>#N/A"")"
```

Comment: Thank you for this tip!

Answer (score 1):

You can use AGGREGATE and remove the OFFSET which is volatile

```
ws.Range("B" & na.Row + 2).Formula= "=AGGREGATE(9,6,B1:B" & na.Row + 1 & ")"
```

Comment: Seems to have worked like a charm. Thanks so much Scott.

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'Chr(34)':

```
ws.Range("B" & na.Row + 2).Formula = "=SUMIF(OFFSET(B1,,,ROW()-1,1)," & Chr(34) & "<>#N/A" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Edit: Deleted quotes written by mistake